# Google Maps API v3, jQuery , Tabs, map not showing on hidden div

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This question had already been addressed multiple times, but all the solutions don't fix the problem in my case. It's as many already wrote: tabs used to display different parts of content, when loading the map in tab1 i.e. the one that opens on pageload, it displays fine.

When loading the map inside one of the other tabs, that need to be clicked, to be called, it doesn't draw the map as it is supposed to.

I already tried adding the google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); when the tab is clicked, but it doesn't do anything.

Here is my code, i am going crazy over this, have spent 10+ hours trying all suggestions !

This is the part that handles the tabs being clicked :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Default Action
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content



    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content

    if (activeTab=='#tab4') { 

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );
    }



    $(activeTab).fadeIn(

    ); //Fade in the active content


    return false;
});
```

});

When using an alert to see if the code is called on tab4 it works.

Here is the googlemaps code

```
    function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $lattie; ?>, <? echo $langie; ?>),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I am calling intitalize() in the body tag, changing this to the place where i am calling the resize, doesn't solve it either.

Finally the bit that shows the div with the map-canvas :

```
        <li id="four">
   <div id="map-canvas" style="width:575px; height:500px;float:left;border:1px solid #d74c15;"></div>
    </li>
```

As i said, i am going crazy over this, i just can't get it to work, any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you please help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944546/google-maps-v3-shows-map-wrong-with-jquery-and-bootstrap-rails-4

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit tricky in one of my projects some time ago I got stuck on the same thing while trying to hide and show the map via a link.For me the resize event handler was all I needed but make sure to add the following code after it:

**UPDATE here is the complete function used.**

```
function showMap(){
  if(animating == false)
  {
    animating = true;

    if(mapVisible == false)
    {
      $("#map-wrapper").animate({
        height:352
      },500,function(){

        $("#create-event-map").fadeIn("fast");
        google.maps.event.trigger(eventsMap, 'resize');
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(38,24);
        eventsMap.setCenter(center);
        $("#show-map-wrapper a").html("Hide map");
        mapVisible = true;
        animating = false;

      })
    }
    else
    {
      $("#create-event-map").fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $("#map-wrapper").animate({
          height:0
        },500);
        $("#show-map-wrapper a").html("Show map");
        mapVisible = false;
        animating = false;
      })
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

working example here: http://goo.gl/2syX8

it's in the create.event.init.js file if you want to check it out

**UPDATE**

In your case if you want to refresh the map you should change this code:

```
if (activeTab=='#tab4') { 

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );
}



$(activeTab).fadeIn(

); //Fade in the active content
```

With this:

```
if(activeTab == 'YOUR TAB ID')
{
   $(activeTab).fadeIn(function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(<LAT>,<LNG>);
        map.setCenter(center);
        map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );
   })
}
```

Store the last used lat and lng and replace them in this piece of code.

Comment: Might be a bit dumb of me, but i am primarily a php/mysql coder, and not that familiar with javascript. So can you tell me how to implement the code above into the code that i have provided ? Sorry for being a noob :)

Comment: do you create a div with id map-canvas in every <li> element? I suppose you want to load maps in all of your <li> elements ?

Comment: no, i just need it in #tab4 , this is the tab called location, hence the need for the map :)

Comment: I tried your answer, editted the right places for the tabid and the lat,lang, but it still doesn't work :(